How to apply data transformation pipeline on unseen data on task of time-series classification?
I am working on a task of classifiying human activity by given pose data. Due to a quality of images when applying pose estimator model, it contains number of missing values. My data transformation pipeline for this training dataset includes missing values interpolation and backfill/forwardfill imputing with pre-defined limit.
My question is: when and where to apply this pipeline on training data: on whole dataset or on each slice, that will be given using sliding window?
Since on inference I will get pose data frame by frame in real-time till collecting slice of window_size length, should I apply pipeline above on this window?
